# Using a functions script in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a doubt about doing something or not in order to keep the good practices in **Zend Framework.**

Lots of times I need to use some functions like: http://www.paulferrett.com/2009/php-camel-case-functions/ or another around the application. The problem is that As i need it on the whole project I can not define as a method of a model, so I tried to use it as helpers.

Now I do not want to use this as helpers because I thing it's not a good practice using view helpers in controllers or models.

I have the following idea: Including a script called **functions.php** in the **index.php** of the Zend Application.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of putting anything into the global namespace, as you risk a name collision any time you do so. I prefer to put generic utility functions like this in an appropriate class within my application's namespace:

```
class MyApp_Util
{
    public static function foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can call with MyApp_Util::foo().

If you've got lots of these types of functions, you can break them down into more appropriate classes:

```
MyApp_Geo_Util::foo();
MyApp_Math_Util::baz();
MyApp_String_Util::bar();
```

Or the 5.3 style if you prefer:

```
\MyApp\Geo\Util::foo();
\MyApp\Math\Util::baz();
\MyApp\String\Util::bar();
```