# How do I create a functions.php file on Zend

Tags: function, zend-framework

I have some general functions like printObject, mysql2date and other that i wan't to use it site wide. Where should i place the functions.php file (or any other filename) in the ZF drectory and how should i call the functions?

I tried now to set them up in library/helpers/action/Utils.php but than i have to call them like this:

```
$this->_helper->utils->deg($page, true)
```

And the main problem is that this works only in the controller and not in the .phtml files.

Comment: We're just using some kind of "Util" Class, located in /library/App/Utils.php with static methods.

Comment: and how do you call the methods?

Comment: We declare them as static "public static function convert();" -> App_Utils::convert();

Comment: So i created the following folder structure: library/Plugins/Utils.php. After this in the application Bootstrap.php I called something like this: $frontController->registerPlugin(new Plugins_Utils()) and than in the index.phtml file I call it like this Plugins_Utils::mysql2date('d/m/Y', $page->date_added). So it works, but is it also the right method?

Comment: Use ActionHelpers for Controllers, ViewHelpers for Views. Or try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299396/using-a-functions-script-in-zend-framework